# Alinear texto en carousel responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy tratando de agregar texto a una imagen dentro de un carrusel, pero este no alinea bien los textos, y ya he intentado muchas cosas, pero con ninguna logro hacer que me funcione y sea responsive.
Por ejemplo, actualmente tengo

```
    <!-- Boostrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <div id="Publicaciones" class="publicaciones" style="border: red solid 3px;">
      <br><br><br>
      <h1 style="text-align: center; color:black;">Publicaciones</h1>

      <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>First slide label</h5>
              <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>Second slide label</h5>
              <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.publicaciones {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 750px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-control-prev{
  background: rgba(209, 215, 4, 0.51);
  color: #fff;
  width: 42px;
  height: 163px;
  left: 10%;
  top: 25%;
  position: absolute;
}

.carousel-control-next {
  background: rgba(209, 215, 4, 0.51);
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 42px;
  height: 163px;
  left: 90%;
  top: 25%;
}

.carousel-inner{
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 50px rgba(120, 143, 156, 0.25);
  display: block;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 500px;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.carrusel {
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-10%);
  top: auto;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-item.carrusel{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.absolute-div {
  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
}

.item {
  position:relative;
}

.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
  background-color: #141414;
}

.carousel-indicators .active{
  background-color: #D1D704;
}

.carousel-item img{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

Y lo que consigo con esto
[image: Have it]

No se acerca a lo que busco
[image: Need it]

La imagen es solo representativa

Comment: Podés crear un snippet con el botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: @padaleiana Lo he intentado, pero siempre hay algo que no queda bien ajustado cuando cambio a dispositivo movil

Comment: Yo es que estoy en contra de usar apenas CSS extra en bootstrap. Luego cuesta mucho de mantener... ¿Has probado con insertar un `card` en lugar de todo eso?  Son bastante flexibles. Aquí te dejo su enlace en su manual: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/card/

Comment: @masterguru Ohhh se me habían olvidado, tienes razón, probaré implementarlo y te comento sii funciona :D Gracias!!